# How can I fetch API?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to fetch the API in React with axios.
All of the code here,/********************************************/

**Index.js Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar/searchbar';
import './style.css';
import dictionary from './API/dictionary';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      word:''
    };
  }

  changeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({word: e.target.value})
  }
  onSearchSubmit = async (e) => {
     const response = await dictionary.get(`/?define=${this.state.word}`)
  console.log(response);
    this.setState({word:this.state.word});
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div className='ui container'>
        <SearchBar 
          change={this.changeHandler}
          onSubmitted={this.onSearchSubmit}
          value={this.state.word}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Below is Search Bar Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
const SearchBar = (props)=> {
  return (
    <div className='search-bar ui segment'>
      <form onSubmit={props.onSubmitted} className='ui form'>
        <div className='field '>
          <label>Search Bar </label>
          <input type='text'
                placeholder='Type any word to know the meaning' 
                onChange={props.change}
                value={props.value}
                /> 
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
export default SearchBar;
```

** Below is Axios Instances:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default axios.create({
  baseUrl: 'https://googledictionaryapi.eu-gb.mybluemix.net'
});
```

What will be proper code? that can fetch data from this api? I am trying again and again but failed.

Comment: can you share the error details that you are facing

Comment: Hi @GK, please expand on your question. `I am trying to fetch the API in React with axios` is not very concise. What are you trying to fetch? When? What is the final end point?

Comment: @BapaiahMalasani  I was trying to fetch data from (https://googledictionaryapi.eu-gb.mybluemix.net). I got my answer thanks for responding.

Comment: @mgarcia thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change `baseUrl` to `baseURL` and will work.

**index.js Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar/searchbar';
import './style.css';
import dictionary from './API/dictionary';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      word:''
    };
  }

  changeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({word: e.target.value}, ()=> this.onSearchSubmit())
  }
  onSearchSubmit = async (e) => {
     const response = await dictionary.get(`/?define=${this.state.word}`)
  console.log(response);
    this.setState({word:this.state.word});
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div className='ui container'>
        <SearchBar 
          change={this.changeHandler}
          onSubmitted={this.onSearchSubmit}
          value={this.state.word}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App
```

**dictionary.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default axios.create({
    baseURL: `https://googledictionaryapi.eu-gb.mybluemix.net`,
});
```

and no changes in `searchbar.js`. I changed index.js a little bit and will send request onChange of input.